# getLocationAbsUrl vs getCurrentUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In protractor, globally available `browser` object has two methods:

- [`getLocationAbsUrl()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.getLocationAbsUrl)

> Returns the current absolute url from AngularJS.

- [`getCurrentUrl()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl)

> Schedules a command to retrieve the URL of the current page.

It is not quite clear and obvious what is the difference between the two. To this very moment, I've been using `getCurrentUrl()` only.

When should we use `getLocationAbsUrl()`? Which use-cases does it cover?

---

I cannot recall anything similar to `getLocationAbsUrl()` in other selenium language bindings. It looks pretty much protractor-specific.

Comment: `getLocationAbsUrl` is definitely Protractor (/angular) specific, uses `$location` on the angular element: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L617 . Where as, as you mention, `getCurrentUrl()` is selenium/webdriver. Not answering because I don't know when each is preferred - also interested in an answer.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I never felt the need to use neither. I always do assertions and waiting on specific locators (elements) rather that urls, because it is common situation to have a url change before a specific portion of your page is inserted into the dom.  So I find it more stable to to wait for changes in the dom rather than changes in the url.

Comment: @Dziamid we do use explicit waits to wait for changes in the DOM too, that makes the tests more reliable and helps to avoid surprises. But there are cases when the url location needs to be checked too. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**GitHub source for [getCurrentUrl](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L795)**

```
webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl = function() {
  return this.schedule(
      new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.GET_CURRENT_URL),
      'WebDriver.getCurrentUrl()');
};
```

Uses the `schedule()` -> `command()` wrappers to resolve a promise from  `WebDriver.getCurrentUrl()`

---

**GitHub source for [Protractor.getLocationAbsUrl](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L617)**

```
functions.getLocationAbsUrl = function(selector) {
  var el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (angular.getTestability) {
    return angular.getTestability(el).
        getLocation();
  }
  return angular.element(el).injector().get('$location').absUrl();
};
```

Simply a wrapper around `$location.absUrl()` with a wait for the **AngularJS** library to load

---

**Current URL vs Absolute URL**

given app URL:

```
http://www.example.com/home/index.html#/Home
```

*Current URL* resolves to more of a URI

```
/home/index.html#/Home
```

*Absolute URL* resolves to

```
http://www.example.com/home/index.html#/Home
```

**When do you want to use absolute URL:** You want to use the Full Domain URL, rather than the local navigation (URI), you want the *Absolute URL*.

- If your application makes calls for the *Current URL*, your tests should call `getCurrentUrl()`.
- If your code makes requests for *Absolute URL*, your tests should call `getLocationAbsUrl()`.

Comment: Thank you, Dave, for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Basically they should do the same thing, return the URL of the page.

From this bug report:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/132

it seems that `IEDriver` for **Selenium** was always returning the first loaded page, not the current one. So the protractor team implemented a JS call to Angular's `$location` to always return the **URL** correctly via **Javascript**, not **Webdriver** protocol.

Answer (score 2):

As stated previously 
the getLocationAbsUrl - returns a full path to the current location.

`browser.get('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api');
expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl())
    .toBe('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api');`

The getCurrentUrl is utilized in a promise (schedule) to retrieve the URL of the current page.  Typically, you would only use the getCurrentUrl when scheduling.

`webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl = function()
{
    return this.schedule(new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.GET_CURRENT_URL),'WebDriver.getCurrentUrl()');
}`

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`getLocationAbsUrl()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getLocationAbsUrl) is now deprecated, and should not be use anymore.
You should use [`getCurrentUrl()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl) instead.

Here is the related [Github commit](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3969/files) by Protractor.